# How to implement angularjs async?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS v1.5.8, My requirement is when i click the Next button it'll display 'Processing...' inside button as text before complete the operation, i have included the $q with my services to get the asynchronous facility, but not working. please see my below codes.

**Service**

```
mainApp.factory('PINVerificationServices', ['$http', '$rootScope','$q', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        IsPermitted: function (param) {
            return $q($http({
                url: '/Api/ApiPINVerification/IsPermitted/' + param,
                method: 'POST',
                async: true
            }));
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
mainApp.controller('PINVerificationController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $window,$q, PINVerificationServices) {
    $scope.SubmitText = "Next";

    $scope.Next = function () {
    $scope.SubmitText = "Processing...";
    PINVerificationServices.IsPermitted($scope.PIN).then(function (result) {
         $scope.SubmitText = "Next";
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="list-group list-group-sm">
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="PIN" placeholder="PIN" required id="PIN" name="PIN" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="Next()">{{SubmitText}}</button>
```

Comment: `but not working` - have you tried the simplest of debugging? like checking the **developer** tools console and network tabs? They provide a lot of information for real developers

Comment: I have checked @JaromandaX , its giving $q is not defined error. Thanks

Comment: `i have included the $q with my services` - right ... and did you include the q library in your page?

Comment: inject `$q` in factory, like : `function ($http, $rootScope, $q)`

Comment: `$q` isn't needed there at all, as `$http` already returns a promise.. Removing `$q` function wrapper should solve  your problem

Comment: Removed $q, but not getting async result. @PankajParkar

Comment: @sebu any error in console after suggested change?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Api/ApiPINVerification/IsPermitted/' + param
        });
```

Comment: Not Working @Sergaros

Comment: can you show output of console.log(PINVerificationServices.IsPermitted($scope.PIN))

Comment: But another problem, not working with nested http service calling.

Comment: Suppose you have called IsPermitted($scope.PIN) function first, then again you have called another function PINVerificationServices.GetStudentInformationByPIN($scope.PIN) inside IsPermitted($scope.PIN) function.

Comment: Don't nest those calls. Just have the calls inside a function that passes a variable back and forth until you have verified the user.

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes (from your requirement of nested `$http`).

In **factory** Use only `$http`, and no need of `$rootScope` as well, It should be like :

```
    mainApp.factory('PINVerificationServices', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
               IsPermitted: function (param) {
                return $http({
                    url: '/Api/ApiPINVerification/IsPermitted/' + param,
                    method: 'POST'
                   });
                },

               GetStudentInformationByPIN : function () {
                return $http({
                    url: '/Api/ApiPINVerification/GetStudentInformationByPIN /',//your api url
                    method: 'GET'
                    });
               }
          };
    }]);
```

In **controller** make use of `$q.all()` :

```
       mainApp.controller('PINVerificationController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $window,$q, PINVerificationServices) {
       $scope.SubmitText = "Next";
       $scope.Next = function () {
            $scope.SubmitText = "Processing...";                      
            $q.all([PINVerificationServices.IsPermitted($scope.PIN),
            PINVerificationServices.GetStudentInformationByPIN($scope.PI‌N), 
             //other promises
            ]).then(function (result) {
                     if(result[0].data){
                         $scope.SubmitText = "Next";
                     }
                     if(result[1].data){
                         // studentdata response handling
                     }
                    });
            }
        }
```